# Symfony 4 Messenger issue

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-messenger

I'm experiencing an issue on the messenger component,

I have two messages classes and two handlers and when I execute

```
php bin/console debug:messenger
```

I get the these results:

[image: result one]

[image: result two]

As you can see in the two results I have different handler every time (`DeliveryMQHandler` or `OrderMQHandler`) but I need the both.

If someone got an idea this is my messenger configuration file :

```
framework:
messenger:
    # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
    # failure_transport: failed

    transports:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
        async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
        # failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
        # sync: 'sync://'

    routing:
        # Route your messages to the transports
        'App\Ressource\Message\Order\OrderMQ': async
        'App\Ressource\Message\Delivery\DeliveryMQ': async
```

The DeliveryMQHandler :

```
<?php

    namespace App\Ressource\Message\Handler;


    use App\Ressource\Message\Delivery\DeliveryMQ;
    use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;

    const XML_FOLDER = 'C:/tmp/';

    class DeliveryMQHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
    {

        public function __invoke(DeliveryMQ $deliveryMQ)
        {
            $fileName = 'LCT_GET_DELIVERY_LOCATION_'.date('Y-m-d').'_'.time().'_'.mt_rand(1000, 9999).'.xml';
            $filePath = XML_FOLDER.$fileName;

            $xml = $deliveryMQ->getContent();

            $fileHandler = fopen($filePath, 'w+');
            fwrite($fileHandler,$xml);
            fclose($fileHandler);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

The OrderMQHandler :

```
<?php

namespace App\Ressource\Message\Handler;

use App\Ressource\Message\Order\OrderMQ;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;

const XML_FOLDER = 'C:/tmp/';

class OrderMQHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{

    public function __invoke(OrderMQ $orderMQ)
    {
        $fileName = 'LCT_'.date('Y-m-d').'_'.time().'_'.mt_rand(1000, 9999).'.xml';
        $filePath = XML_FOLDER.$fileName;

        $xml = $orderMQ->getContent();

        $fileHandler = fopen($filePath, 'w+');
        fwrite($fileHandler,$xml);
        fclose($fileHandler);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The message class are too big to show there but they are well implemented and I'm quite sure they are not the problem because the `getContent()` method result is OK every time.

The autowiring property is set to true in the services.yml
The different class are well listed when I do the following command: `php bin/console debug:container`

Finnaly the stack trace of the error inside the `php bin/console messenger:consume -vvv` :
[image: stack trace]

**EDIT :**
The structure of the two class =>
OrderMQ class :

```
    <?php


namespace App\Ressource\Message\Order;


use App\Entity\Address;
use App\Entity\Customer;
use App\Entity\OrderHead;
use DOMDocument;

class OrderMQ {

    private $content;

    public function __construct(Customer $customer, Address $address, OrderHead $order)
    {
         //create the xml to send in the handler...
    }

    public function getContent() {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $content
     * @return OrderMQ
     */
    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

DeliveryMQ class :

```
namespace App\Ressource\Message\Delivery;


use DOMDocument;

class DeliveryMQ  {

    private $content;

    public function __construct($zipCode, $town)
    {
        //create the xml to send in the handler...
    }

    public function getContent() {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $content
     * @return deliveryMQ
     */
    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean each time you call `bin/console debug:messenger` you get different results? No need to post the whole message class (which, btw, shouldn't be too big; a good design calls for lightweight messages), but post at least the basic definition for these two message classes.

Comment: you mean each time you call bin/console debug:messenger you get different results? => yes exactly. And the class create xml with dom document and thoses XML are good I will edit the question with the structure of thoses class

Comment: did you clear the cache ?

Comment: Yes I already try @YoussefSaoubou